# Truncated normals in python and R when 'a' and 'b' are too far from mean

Tags: python, r, scipy

When trying to get the pdf of a truncated normal distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
truncnorm.pdf(-31, np.inf, -30, loc=0, scale=1)
```

it works fine. But if the upper bound is too far from the mean, the probability assigned to samples in the non-truncated side (there where the overall mass should be 1) are NaN:

```
# -41 is one of the points with highest probability. Why nan?
>truncnorm.pdf(-41, np.inf, -40, loc=0, scale=1)
nan

# 39 is impossible since it lays in the truncated side
>truncnorm.pdf(-39, np.inf, -40, loc=0, scale=1)
0.0
```

Is there a bug due to numerical precission issues or something? 
Is there another way to do this?

**Update 1** (with R library "truncnorm"):

It seems to be a common issue. Same problem with R "truncnorm" library:

```
 > dtruncnorm(-41, a=-Inf, b=-40, mean = 0, sd = 1)
 [1] NaN
```

**Update 2** (with R library "msm"):

In his blog, Christian Robert [pointed out](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/truncated-normal/) to the "msm" library that implements his [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4010).

However, it collapses for this case as well:

```
> dtnorm(-41, mean = 0, sd=1, lower=-Inf, upper=-40)
[1] NaN
```

Comment: I looks like this issue can give some hint. Looks like the function is not thought to work with a high numerical precision: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1489

Comment: This is an issue for R truncnorm library as well, and even when using approximations, see Christian Roberts post: http://xianblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/painful-truncnorm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation for the truncnorm is based on the cdf of the normal distribution.

It's not possible to represent the cdf in floating point (double) precision so far out in the tail.

```
>>> stats.norm.cdf(-37)
5.7255712225239266e-300
>>> stats.norm.cdf(-38)
0.0

>>> stats.norm.pdf(-37)
2.120006551524606e-298
>>> stats.norm.pdf(-38)
1.0972210519949712e-314
>>> stats.norm.pdf(-39)
0.0

>>> np.finfo(float).tiny
2.2250738585072014e-308
```

The only way to implement this would be a direct calculation or approximation of the truncated distribution, not through the special functions for the normal distribution.

I have never seen a usecase where I would want to use this.

Comment: If you replace nans by zeros, then you have only zeros left, which wouldn't make a density. There is no way around this except for switching to multiprecision calculations (mpmath) or providing tail specific `special` functions.

Comment: Exactly, you can't just replace NaN by 0 because the NaN part is actually what is left after truncation, and thus it has to be renormalized so that it sums to 1.

Comment: Thanks @user333700, it is reassuring at list. My case is a Gibbs sampling for a mixture of probit regressions. It is quite similar to whqt is described in this paper: http://jmlr.org/papers/volume10/shahbaba09a/shahbaba09a.pdf

I'll review my algorithm in case I'm doing some nonsense.

Comment: @user333700 you are right, I misread the function call, I thought NaNs were due to zeroes, not where there is actually something.